# How to set root password on mysql server on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, passwords, root

I've been struggling with this for some time. I have Mysql 5.7.20 in my EC2 instance and want to set / change root password. So I do:

1. sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

which gives the follow error:
mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

so I do:

3. mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld

which gives:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/run/mysqld’: Permission denied

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: See my answer below, and if you have trouble with any of the syntax or commands, update your question with that specific problem and maybe someone can assist with any errors you are receiving.

Comment: sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld

Comment: @KrzysztofMusialik Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful answer. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual:

[B.5.3.2 How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)